# xampp vm The address has changed and I can not fix it

Tags: macos, xampp, xampp-vm

I was using xampp vm for a month and clicked on the address 192.168.64.2 and I wanted to reset the files I went into this folder /Users/oriohana/.bitnami I deleted all the files but I run xampp the address 192.168.64.3 I did it exactly 20 times to go back to the normal address 192.168 .64.2 and it's now 192.168.64.25 I want to reset these settings I'll go back to 192.168.64.2 it's really important to me for the project I would love for you to help me

*I have a mac*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [this site](https://www.mrtekno.net/2019/08/how-to-access-localhost-xampp-vm.html) it seems you can hard code the IP. It could have been changed with DHCP too, so if that doesn't work you'll need to change the IP from your DHCP server. (could be your router, could be anything that gives out IPs that that mac is connected to)